# Firewall review using ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, firewall, elastic-stack

I'm looking for a way to perform an automated and centralized firewall review tool by using the ELK stack. I believe it's a nice tool to use in order to achieve this, specifically with Kibana.
By using certain data, I would like to enrich the firewall ruleset.
The firewall rules can be exported in CSV format, the resting data can be adapted to such format.

The data will be comprised of:

- Firewall rules: Source, Destination, Services, Action (drop or accept)
- Inventory of all IPs: IP address(es), support groups, status of the device (dismissed or deployed)
- Addressing scheme of each office: Site, belonging subnet(s)

I have imported all the data, but I have absolutely no idea on how to achieve the correlation between firewall rulesets and relative IP from the inventory and addressing from the offices. It would be nice to have a view of the firewall rule and see if it belongs to a specific site.Bear in mind that multiple firewall rules might have multiple entries (e.g. 10.0.0.0/8 -> 10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2,etc...)

The final objective to this review is to aggregate rules (whenever possible) by optimizing operability and security.

Did anybody find themselves in the same situation? If so, how did you solve it?

I'd appreciate any input you might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
Basically wrote some python scripts which correlate (offline) the information present within the CSV rules and the CSV inventory, and also within the CSV rules and CSV environments/subnets.
After all this, some manual intervention is indeed required to achieve what I'm asking.